# Recommended device for testing Android 2.1

Tags: android, testing

Does anyone have experience testing Android apps on various devices? I'm looking for recommendations on which device would be a good test platform.

Comment: You could try the emulator. Is there a reason why that wouldn't work (i.e. are you doing intensive graphics or hardware-related stuff?)

Comment: Isn't this a matter of opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Samsung I5700 Galaxy Spica for about 1 year, I think it is a very good phone. We used this phone to run Robotium UI tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Motorola quench xt3 for the past six months and I believe its good. Maybe you could give it a try. But still you can make use of your emulator itself which is best for most of the cases except for very few cases where you might need a real device to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If your app can run on the emulator I would recommend that for testing on older devices, otherwise you will have to buy hundreds of handsets :)

I personally would recommend running your app on any device over 2.1 and then set the target SDK version in your manifest file to target 7

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
```